# How spring security Support multiple authorization approaches

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

My project only supports JWT authorization. Now wanted to add one more authorization which was customized by my company.
The problem is it also sends header same with JWT "Authorization=Bears xxxxxx".
so everytime JWT will automatically authorize basing the Key "Authorization" then failed.

My question is how to disable JWT if one of my authorization succeed.

Thanks.

Comment: does it sends any different information than existing JWT authorization?

Comment: maybe AuthenticationManagerResolver??

Comment: @ChandrakantAudhutwar  no, it can't change now...